# Why doesn't this Linux symlink work?

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a symbolic link for the file `logs` inside `home/dir1/` to the file `netlogs` inside `home/dir3/`.

The link is created but when I try to look at the contents of `netlogs` I got this error message:

```
13042432: -bash: cd: netlogs: No such file or directory
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You symlink is broken. It's hard to tell why without any clue about how you created it and what does it look like. Please post `ls -dl home/dir1/netlogs` output (You probably mean `ls -ld $HOME/dir1/netlogs`).

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 joasia None 9 Dec 27 14:06 netlogs -> dir1/logs`

Comment: Would it matter that I am using Cygwin?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your symlink is broken. Delete it with `rm netlogs`. Recreate it using absolute paths, like this:

```
ln -s /home/dir3/logs /home/dir1/netlogs
```

The first argument is the existing real file or directory.

The second argument is the link that will point to the first argument.

Extra tip:

> ```
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 joasia None 9 Dec 27 14:06 netlogs -> dir1/logs
> ```

The `netlogs -> dir1/logs` means the `netlogs` is a link to `dir1/logs` relative from the current directory. This looks wrong, because in the question you wrote that you want to link to `logs` which is inside `home/dir3`, not in `dir1`.

Comment: I'm using the syntax you provided, though still when i try to `cat netlogs` when within `dir3` it says that there is `No such file or directory` and yes the link does exist as confirmed by `ls -l` showing `lrwxrwxrwx 1 joasia None 14 Dec 27 15:19 netlogs -> home/dir1/logs`

Comment: It looks like the link is pointing to `home/dir1/logs` instead of `/home/dir1/logs`. The starting `/` is important.

Comment: Oh woops, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your symbolic link with a path that will work wherever you are, either an absolute one like

```
ln -s $HOME/dir3/logs $HOME/dir1/netlogs
```

**or better**, **a relative path** which will allow the upper directory to be moved elsewhere without the link being broken.

```
ln -s ../dir3/logs dir1/netlogs
```

Comment: The target should be `dir3/logs`. It is the link that is `netlogs`.

Comment: @janos To be honest, I wasn't him but have to admit you first got the names in the right order so +1 now.